# Uses per Customer limit of magento coupons is not working

Tags: magento-1.8, coupon-codes

I have limit the Uses per Customer to 1 only. But unfortunately it's not working when I used the Free Shipping for matching items. Tested the coupon many times but the store is still  accepting it.

**Rule Information:**
Customer Groups: General
Uses per Coupon: 1
Uses per Customer: 1
Priority: 0

Currently using Magento CE 1.8.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Were you logged in when you placed the orders and used the coupon?

Comment: yes. and i set general for customer groups.